# Foreman and the PATH environment variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo, foreman, upstart

I use foreman export to create upstart scripts (on ubuntu). Foreman generate an upstart script like that :

```
start on starting app
stop on stopping app
respawn

exec su - ubuntu -c ...
```

**Problem** : before launching the app, I need to run a bunch of scripts that change the      environment (including the PATH). But, executing something with su/sudo on ubuntu reset the PATH. And, my app can't run without the PATH set by the scripts. Is there any workaround ??

Comment: actually, executing the scripts in the pre start script does the work.

Answer (score 1):

Try su -p, which preserves the environment [(manpage)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/su)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use "sudo -E"

> ```
>     -E          The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security
>                 policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing
>                 environment variables. The security policy may return an error
>                 if the -E option is specified and the user does not have
>                 permission to preserve the environment.
> ```